# How can I resolve the -4058 Error in creating a new NX workspace?

Tags: npm, npx

**When I try to execute the `npx create-nx-workspace@latest` command the following error is displayed.**

```
F:\Learnings\NX>npx create-nx-workspace@latest
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\haree\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\haree\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\haree\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-30T17_05_00_744Z-debug-0.log
```

May I know the root cause & the fix for this error?